# No database connection after deployment (Java Hibernate)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, deployment, struts2

I am creating an app for school that generates business rules.
The front end consists of Apex and the backend is a java application that uses hibernate to access the database.

To communicate between Apex and Java I am using a rest service (using struts2).
This works fine when I deploy the application in my IDE (netbeans). But then it runs on my localhost. This way the Apex application can not connect to it. (The Apex application is hosted by my school)

So I tried deploying my application using various websites. The rest service part still works and I can connect the java app with my Apex application.

The problem is that the java application cant seem to connect to the database as soon as i deploy it online.
The glassfish console shows this when I try to get data from the database:

(Tosad is the name of the project/course)

```
[2016-01-08T15:23:07.004+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] 
[tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1452266587004] [levelValue: 800] [[
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2016-01-08 15:23:07.004--ServerSession(1585495182)--       
Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [TOSAD].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'TOSAD' in SerialContext[
myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
       java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
       java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} 
[Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TOSAD not found]]]
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml (I replaced some info for safety purposes)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate     Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ondora02.hu.nl:PORT:COURSE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USERNAME</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASSWORD</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package Service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static String orclcfg = "nl.hu.ict.jpa.oracle";
    private static String mysqlcfg = "nl.hu.ict.jpa.mysql";
    private static boolean mysql = false;
    private static String dbcfg = orclcfg;
    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    //entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("nl.hu.ict.jpa.oracle" );
    static {
        try {
            if (!mysql) {
                dbcfg = orclcfg;
            }

            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(dbcfg);

        } catch (Throwable th) {
            System.err.println("Initial EntityManagerFactory creation failed" + th);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
        }
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is somewhat clear.  The JNDI resource named `TOSAD` cannot be located on your remote deployed server.  Make sure it is configured on the remote server like you likely have done on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks! After a few google searches I fixed the problem